# Wide character in IO::Socket::INET send

Tags: perl, sockets

i am trying to send some text using IO::Socket::INET here is my code :

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr => $IP,
                     PeerPort => $Port,
                     Proto => 'udp',
                     Timeout => 1) or die 'Could not create socket: $!';
        
        $socket->send($text) or die "Send UDP packet error: $!";
```

but I have some non utf-8 characters on thetext i am sending , Then I am getting this message any idea how to fix it?

```
Wide character in send at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Socket.pm
```

Comment: Don't send wide characters. You have to encode them to octets first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets are a byte stream and not a character stream. This means you need to encode your character string into bytes. There are various character encodings possible but the commonly used one is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), where a single character is presented with something between one to six bytes (one byte for ASCII etc).

```
 use Encode 'encode';
 my $bytes = encode('UTF-8', $text);
 $socket->send($bytes);
```

Note that you need to do the reverse on the receiver end if you want to get back the characters from the bytes, i.e. use `Encode::decode`.

See also the relevant parts in the documentation, especially in [perlunifaq](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#When-should-I-decode-or-encode%3f) the parts about when to encode and what happens if you don't encode.